# Restricting Multiple Generic Parameters to add two different number types(integer and floats) and return the result in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am new to Rust and tried to pass in Generic Parameters to a function that takes different types. I want to add them both and return the result from it.

I know that a trait must be defined on the parameters to restrict the Types. I also know there are issues with **adding a** **float** and **integer**. Anyways, how can I perform this without using the `num` crate that. I tried restricting them with traits but I guess one of `integer` or `float` types do not implement that trait. And I really don't know where to go from here:

```
fn add_two <T1,U2> (var_a:T1,var_b:U2) -> T1
     where T1:std::ops::Add<Output=T1>,
           U2:std::ops::Add<Output=T1>{
            
           var_a+var_b
     }
```

And why is the return type a mismatch? Even when the output of the Add trait is defined as T1 in both the generic parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints you wrote mean that `T1 + T1 = T1` and `U2 + U2 = T1`, but what you're doing it `T1 + U2 = T1`. Luckily, [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Add.html) take a generic parameter `Rhs`, defaulted to `Self` but can be changed, that is used to specify the type on the right:

```rust
fn add_two<T1, U2>(var_a: T1, var_b: U2) -> T1
where
    T1: std::ops::Add<U2, Output = T1>,
{
    var_a + var_b
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. I suppose now I have to implement custom traits for addition of integer and float types to make this work.